# when throttling chrome to offline the navigator.onLine is still true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, offline

chrome dev tools network throttling offline still shows `navigatior.onLine` as **true**.

I want to test the offline experience for a webapp. I am checking if the device is online or offline and call different functions then (no ajax calls i.e.).

How can I archive an offline behavior with chrome, without disconnecting my machine. I still need the connection for other services.

Comment: There is a ticket for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1162822&q=navigator.onLine&can=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting `navigator.onLine = false` doesn't work, but you can completely overwrite the "onLine" property:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, "onLine", {value: false})
```

If you want to restore it later, keep a reference to the old property descriptor:

```
var oldOnLineDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    navigator.constructor.prototype, "onLine")
// ...
Object.defineProperty(navigator, "onLine", oldOnLineDescriptor)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 window.addEventListener('online', onOnline);
 window.addEventListener('offline', onOffline);

function onOnline() { 
  window.isOnline = true;
  // do what you want 
}

function onOffline() {
  window.isOnline=false 
  // do what you want
}
```

Comment: the variable window.isOnline remains undefined ... so, this does not work.